# dplyr::mutate fails when calling predict() within an if_else() block

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr::mutate to assign fitted values from either a loess() or lm() model, depending on the value of a user specified 'flag'. I was trying to implement this using an if_else() function as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = seq(1:10), y = 10*x + rnorm(10,0,2))

loess_model <- loess(y ~ x, data = df, span = 0.75)
lm_model <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

# this does not work
loess_not_lm <- TRUE
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(yhat = if_else(loess_not_lm == TRUE,
                        predict(loess_model, newdata=pick(x)),
                        predict(lm_model, newdata=pick(x)),
                        NA_real_))
```

When I execute the code above, I get the following error message:

*Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `yhat = if_else(...)`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `true` must have size 1, not size 10.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.*

Conversely, predict() seems to work if it is not called from within an if_else() function:

```
# this executes without errors
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(fit_ = predict(loess_model, newdata=pick(x)))

# the following also executes without errors
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(fit_ = predict.lm(lm_model, newdata=pick(x)))
```

I could implement this with an if() statement. For example:

```
  if (model_type == 'loess') {
    df$fit_ = predict(loess_model, newdata=df)
  } else {
    df$fit_ = predict(lm_model, newdata=df)
  }
```

... but was curious why this wouldn't work using dplyr::mutate(fit_ = if_else())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get

```
df %>% 
    mutate(fit_ = predict(loess_model, newdata=pick(x)))

# A tibble: 10 × 3
       x     y  fit_
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  10.2  7.52
 2     2  17.3 19.9 
 3     3  31.2 31.1 
 4     4  40.6 41.5 
 5     5  48.2 49.9 
 6     6  60.5 59.5 
 7     7  71.5 68.3 
 8     8  82.1 77.5 
 9     9  89.6 87.6 
10    10  99.8 98.4
```

using your `mutate()` above, then you should insert a `rowwise()`:

```
df %>% 
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(yhat = if_else(loess_not_lm == TRUE,
                          predict(loess_model, newdata=pick(x)),
                          predict(lm_model, newdata=pick(x)),
                          NA_real_))
# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Rowwise: 
       x     y  yhat
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  10.2  7.52
 2     2  17.3 19.9 
 3     3  31.2 31.1 
 4     4  40.6 41.5 
 5     5  48.2 49.9 
 6     6  60.5 59.5 
 7     7  71.5 68.3 
 8     8  82.1 77.5 
 9     9  89.6 87.6 
10    10  99.8 98.4
```

Answer (score 1):

As your test `loess_not_lm == TRUE` is a vector of length 1 `if_else`  expects a vector of length 1 for the `yes` and `no` values too.

Instead you could (or have to) use an `if {} else {}`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(x = seq(1:10), y = 10 * x + rnorm(10, 0, 2))

loess_model <- loess(y ~ x, data = df, span = 0.75)
lm_model <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

loess_not_lm <- TRUE

df %>%
  mutate(yhat = if (loess_not_lm) {
    predict(loess_model, newdata = pick(x))
  } else {
    predict(lm_model, newdata = pick(x))
  })
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>        x     y  yhat
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1  8.88  8.78
#>  2     2 19.5  20.3 
#>  3     3 33.1  31.0 
#>  4     4 40.1  40.9 
#>  5     5 50.3  50.9 
#>  6     6 63.4  62.4 
#>  7     7 70.9  70.9 
#>  8     8 77.5  79.0 
#>  9     9 88.6  88.5 
#> 10    10 99.1  99.0
```

Comment: Yup. This way your  `if_else` will work. Just a remark: No need to test for `== TRUE`. Simply do `if_else(loess_not_lm, ...)`.

Comment: Thank @stefan! So the answer to my question "Why won't mutate(yhat = if_else(...)) work" is that my test/flag variable (loess_not_lm) should be a vector with a length equal to the number of rows in my dataframe df. I accepted the other answer because it directly answered my question, but your helpful response helped me arrive at another solution to my problem (i.e. mutate(loess_not_lm = loess_not_lm, yhat = if_else(...). I wish I stackoverflow would let me give checkmarks to multiple responses!).

Comment: That's absolutely fine for me. But be aware that `rowwise` my result in a considerable loss of performance on larger datasets. Hence, if you want to stick with `if_else` I would go for your approach. (: